# Presto Weighted Moving Average Syntax Error

Tags: sql, presto, weighted-average

I'm trying to run the weighted moving average [Silota query](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-weighted-moving-average.html) with similar data in a Presto database but am encountering an error. The same query in the Redshift database has no issues, however in Presto I receive a syntax error:

```
Query failed (#20220505_230258_04927_5xpwi): 
line 14:14: Column 't2.row_number' cannot be resolved io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: 
line 14:14: Column 't2.row_number' cannot be resolved.
```

The data is the same in both databases, why does the query run in Redshift while Presto throws the error?

```sql
WITH t AS
    (select date_trunc('month',mql_date) date, avg(mqls) mqls, row_number() over ()
     from marketing.campaign
        WHERE date_trunc('month',mql_date) > date('2021-12-31')
        GROUP BY 1)
select t.date, avg(t.mqls),
       sum(case
    when t.row_number - t2.row_number = 0 then 0.4 * t2.mqls
    when t.row_number - t2.row_number = 1 then 0.3 * t2.mqls
    when t.row_number - t2.row_number = 2 then 0.2 * t2.mqls
    when t.row_number - t2.row_number = 3 then 0.1 * t2.mqls
end) weighted_avg
       from t
join t t2 on t2.row_number between t.row_number - 3 and t.row_number
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: `date` is also a reserved keyword, so it would be best to not use it as an alias/column name.

Comment: _"The data is the same in both databases, why does the query run in Redshift while Presto throws the error?"_ cause they have different SQL engines with different dialects.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because your SQL assumes that the result of the row_number() window function will be called "row_number".  This is true in Redshift but other databases may infer a different name onto it.  You should alias this to some defined name such as "rn".

Also you have no "order by" clause in your row_number() function which will make the row numbers unpredictable and possibly varying between invocations.